# Validation Controller inside CMS in Silverstripe

Tags: php, backend, silverstripe

At the moment i have a LeftAndMain section named 'Applications' which contains a form with a password field:
[image: LeftAndMain content section]

The code for this is:

```
class Applications extends LeftAndMain {
    static $url_segment = 'applications';
    static $menu_title = 'Applications';
    static $url_rule = '$Action/$ID';

    public function init(){
        parent::init();
    }

    public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null) {
        $fields = new FieldList(
            TextField::create('Password', ' Password')
        );
        $actions = new FieldList(new FormAction('applicationPassword'));
        return new Form($this, "EditForm", $fields, $actions);
    }

    public function applicationPassword($data, Form $form){
        $form->sessionMessage('Correct password. I will redirect you to manage your model', 'success');
        return $this->redirectBack();
    }
}
```

When submiting this form, the action function should validate if it's equaly with something (in my case, it's a key to decrypt data from a database) and then redirect/show the Gridfield.

The second point is a ModelAdmin, where i can manage the data (that are comming from that database) through GridField.
[image: Managing data from a model]

The code for this is:

```
class Applications2 extends ModelAdmin {
    static $url_segment = 'applications2';
    static $menu_title = 'Applications2';

    private static $managed_models = array(
        'SecureFormInput'
    );
}
```

And here is my question: is it possible to do this ? Any suggestions/help becouse i tried for while and no result.

Comment: What you are trying to implement is extra guard for the same model admin. Just use condition in getEditForm() to return your custom form or standard ModelAdmin form. ( noPassword ? showPasswordForm : parent:getEditForm )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding it really hard to figure out what you're *really* trying to do.

Here are a few things that I can see that might still help you though:

1. You wouldn't usually extend `LeftAndMain` directly. 99% of the time, developers are building admin-screens or areas, in which a single or multiple model(s) (`DataObject` subclasses) are managed.
2. In your `Applications` class you have no `$allowed_actions` static. You need this to have at least a single value: `'applicationPassword'` in order to tell SilverStripe which are the legitimate actions this controller can perform.
3. Again, depending on what you're trying to do, you would usually password protect a CMS admin area using the SilverStripe CMS' standard permissions system (See the "Security" menu item). Notice you can authorise users or groups on *some* admin screens.
   If this is what you're trying to do for your various custom controllers, you should ensure your controller declares a `canView()` method. Again see `LeftAndMain.php` for examples.
4. Validation is usually done at a model level. E.g. you have a `DataObject` subclass which you want to manage from within a ModelAdmin. In which case you define a method called `validate()` on your `DataObject` subclass. When editing / creating new instances of this model
   from within your ModelAdmin, the CMS knows to run your `validate()` method, if it finds one on your model.
5. When you say "It isn't working" we really need to know "in what way?" e.g. Do you see an error message, do you not see something you should, if so what etc etc

If none of these points help, what would really help others help you, is if you re-wrote your question *something like* this:

"I am trying to password protect a custom CMS administration screen. I have a model `MyModel` with the following class definition (screenshot or code), and a `ModelAdmin` (screenshot or code). The code should show an error message of the password is bad (a bad password is one that doesn't match one in the database, or doesn't follow a specific format etc etc) or a success message of the password matched a DB entry or did follow a specific pattern or format."

Good luck :-)

Comment: Point 2 is valid for custom controller actions, while Form actions are added to the allowed list automatically.